# Qual a maneira correta de se fazer o template no Django/python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mvc, django, django-templates

Esse tem sido meu primeiro contato com o framework e com mvc/mvt, e estou em duvida, em questão de boas praticas e tals, devo fazer um template pra cada uma das views ou devo fazer apenas um template e ir mudando o conteudo de forma dinamica atraves das views? 
O topo e o rodapé das paginas serão iguais, só não sei qual a melhor forma de fazer isso.

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia fazer um template base onde teria as questões de navbar, rodapé, e coisas recorrentes nos demais templates e usar o sistema de templates do django`{% extends %}` do django para mudar certas partes como por exemplo o titulo, o conteúdo e etc.

Você pode dar uma olhada aqui: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/templates/